# Megento - Areas to create/manage pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento and can't figure out yet where to manage all the pages in admin. For example, I notice www.domain.com/contactus works on my site - the page is there; however I couldn't figure out where the contactus page is. I looked under CMS > Pages, and also looked in Catalog > Manage Categories but couldn't find it either. Those are the 2 places that I know so far that can create pages. What do I miss? Sorry if it's a very basic question. Thanks.